# Does Evolution have 'zoom text' feature?

Tags: thunderbird, email, evolution

Does Evolution email client have the ability to zoom in and out of the text in both the reader panel and the composer window?

I can only find this ability when you open an email in its own window - but not found in any other part of Evolution!

Here, and in Thunderbird (and Outlook for that matter), you can click either <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in or out, and the big one is scrolling back and forth with the mouse wheel while holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key to zoom in and out.

Any thoughts on why its not available in the rest of the windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does have such a feature, try this:

1. Move the mouse pointer over the mail preview window
2. hold down the <kbd>Crtl</kbd> key while scrolling with the mouse wheel

Now the text will be enlarged (scrolling-up) or made smaller (scrolling down). This does not work with message lists, just with the message preview.

Remark: Above assumes you have "focus-follows-mouse" activated. Without that, you might have to activate the preview by clicking into it. And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> works fine here as well for me – again, in the message preview only.

Comment: Thank you! As noted above, I'm really looking for this ability in the 'compose new message' window...any thoughts on that?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've checked that as well and could not find any clue there. All that's left for things like that are little "desktop helper" like `xmag` or `wmagnify` IMHO.